# Comparar a informação de dois data.frames (tabelas) para criar grupos e uma terceira coluna. em R

Tags: r

Eu estou tentando criar grupos diferenciados de empregos do banco de dados do CBO (CLASSIFICAÇÃO BRASILEIRA DE OCUPAÇÃO)
Eles fornecem um CBO2002.csv com duas colunas a coluna "CODIGO" (com o código de cada profissão) e a coluna "PROFISSAO" (com o nome da cada ocupação) em ordem.

ex:
da linha 1 a 28 são os profissionais militares.
da linha 29 a 44 são os políticos
e assim por diante

Eu tenho uma tabela (PROF) com duas colunas, a primeira com uma numeração em sequencia de 1:3108, e a segunda coluna com as profissões. A ideia é criar grupos de profissões e agrupar identificar esses clientes nesses grupos.

por exemplo: profissionais da tabela (PROF) que se encaixam nas ocupações das linhas 1 a 28 da tabela (CBO2002) entram no grupo MILITARES criando uma terceira coluna na tabela (PROF) com o nome de "GRUPOS" com essas profissões identificadas como "MILITAR"

```
    PRO2F <- PROF %>% 
dplyr::mutate(GRUPOS = dplyr::case_when 

( PROFISSAO == "OFICIAL GENERAL DA AERONAUTICA" ~ "MILITAR",
  PROFISSAO == "OFICIAL GENERAL DO EXERCITO" ~ "MILITAR",
))
```

Eu consegui dessa forma sem usar a tabela (CBO2002) de filtro, mas tive de escrever cada profissão e são mais de 3000.

A minha duvida é como posso usar os intervalos da tabela (CBO2002) como filtro para identificar e agrupar as profissões da minha tabela (PROF) entre a linha. Pra não ter de escrever 3000 profissões.

O que eu tentei e não funcionou até agora:

```
PROF2 <- PROF %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(GRUPOS = dplyr::case_when 
    
    ( PROFISSAO == CBO2002[c(1:28),"PROFISSAO"] ~ "MILITAR" ))
```

ou

```
militar<-as.vector(CBO2002[c(1:28),"PROFISSAO"])

PROF2 <- PROF %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(GRUPOS = dplyr::case_when 
    
    ( PROFISSAO == militar ~ "MILITAR" ))
```

Eu sou novato e já agradeço pela atenção.

[CBO2002.csv](https://1drv.ms/x/s!An_uBUeOoXjbgug9IQp0rlRoU9coJw?e=ssOR6r)

[PROF.csv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An_uBUeOoXjbgug_mWNPR8Xj-sKEKQ?e=BTbt0Z)

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o between, comparando os índices do data frame no case_when:

```
library(dplyr)

rows <- rownames(CBO2002)
CBO2002 <- CBO2002 %>%
  mutate(grupo = case_when(
    between(rows,1,28) ~ 'Militar',
    between(rows,29,44) ~ 'Político',
    TRUE ~ 'outros'
  ))
```

Depois renomeia a coluna e faz um join pelo nome da variável

```
CBO2002 <- rename(CBO2002, profissao = TITULO)
inner_join(PROF, CBO2002, by='profissao')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu preciso criar a terceira coluna "GRUPO" na tabela (PROF). A ideia é usar os nomes dos intervalos da tabela (CBO2002) como filtro pra criação dos grupos,(profissões 1:28 = Militar; profissões 29:44 = Politicos,...) comparar com as profissões da tabela (PROF) e aplicar o resultado na coluna "GRUPO" criada na tabela (PROF) na mesma linha da profissão da coluna "PROFISSAO"

Comment: @LucasMoterani, bom dia! Atualizei a resposta, depois da uma olhada. Abraço!